# Firebase storage transfer, bandwidth, download pricing

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am having trouble understanding Firebase storage pricing and what exactly counts as a transfer/download/bandwidth. I am working on a video based app and planned on storing content on Firebase but seeing how quickly I reached the daily free-cap for downloads (1 GB/day) when testing my app for about 3 hours, I am rethinking Firebase for storage. (However I don't know if I should be rethinking it or if thats normal for someone on the free tier)

[image: Firebase storage]

1. Is the *GB downloaded* the same as a bandwidth and transfer charge?
2. When I download a video onto someones device, am I getting a flag/charge for GB downloaded & Download operations every time?
3. Do I also get a bandwidth charge every time someone uploads a video along with upload operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. GB downloaded is the amount of data that is read from your storage bucket(s), while bandwidth and transfer would also include uploads.
2. Yes. If X people download a file, you get charged for X download operations and X times the size of the file in GB downloaded.
3. No, there is no charge for upload bandwidth. There is a charge for upload operations though, as shown in the pricing page and in the screenshot you included.